# block a root domain from refering to a page under my domain?

Tags: redirect, dns

While looking through analytics data I found a root domain pointing to a page under my domain. Here it is:

> The real page: http://sightofnick.com/phone/
> The **fake** page: http://danielitollamar.tk

How do I stop this redirect or whatever it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a frame.  You can try a [frame-buster](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Framekiller), but they may break out a frame-buster-buster

A possible server-side solution is setting the new [X-Frame-Options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/The_X-FRAME-OPTIONS_response_header) response header to SAMEORIGIN.  However, this is only supported in recent browsers.